# how to use orderBy() and Where() same? (Flutter Web)

Tags: flutter

Not load data but it loads indefinitely ♾
if i take off OrderBy then it works
but I need the Order by

code:

```
body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("crush")
          .where("user", isEqualTo: user.email)
          .orderBy("date", descending: true)
          
          .snapshots(),
      builder:
          (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
```

Comment: Don't post images of code, post the code itself as text with the proper formating.

Comment: Check  the debug console.. You'll see a link to create an index for the query you are making. Click on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do composite query like this you need to create [composite index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries). There are two ways to create index for it:

**Create index using error message:**

---

When you try to use a *compound query* without existing index, you will get an error in your *debug console* like this:

> E/flutter (23618): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: [cloud_firestore/failed-precondition] The query requires an index. You can create it here: https://console.firebase.google.com/v1/r/project/yourprojectname/firestore/indexes?create_composite=Ck1wcm9qZWN0cy92b2lkY2hhdGJldGEvZGF0YWJhc2VzLyhkZWZhdWx0KS9jb2xsZWN0aW9uR3JvdXBzL2NvbnRhY3RzL2luZGV4ZXMvXxABGgsKB3VzZW5hbWUQARoGCgJpZBABGgwKCF9fbmFtZV9fEAE

this error have a link to create a missing index with *Firebase console*.
Follow this link, check data and click **create**.

[image]

**Manually create index with Firebase console:**

---

- Go to Firestore section of [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/firestore/data).

[image]

- Go to indexes tab and click **Create Index**.

[image]

- Enter the collection name and set the fields you want to order the index by.

> For non-array and non-map fields, you must select ascending or descending ordering, even if you don't need the field for ordering. Your choice doesn't impact the behavior of equalities in the query.

[image]

- Click **Create**.

Comment: @Kalias29 changes must be done not in your code but in `firebase console`, check updated answer.

Comment: which fields should I put? 
only the timestamp?

Comment: @Kalias29 both, user and date. It allows at least 2 fields or this is not a compound query.

Comment: timestamp (date) I set descending, user how? ascenidng, descending or array?

Comment: @Kalias29 Set ascending. Both ascending and descending index allows equality check, that is what you need.

Comment: I try now, Thanks 

Comment: sorry, if i want use:

Comment: .where("user", isNotEqualTo: user.email)
          .orderBy("date", descending: true)

Comment: this error :                                 Error: [cloud_firestore/failed-precondition] Persistence can only be cleared before a Firestore instance is initialized or after it is terminated.
                        at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:5000/dart_sdk.js:5333:11)
                .....