# Firebase Query in Flutter Not Returning Results

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have 2 queries in my flutter app that reference the same information in firebase. One is filtered by the user's id and the other is filtered by the patient's id. Both queries work but only the query that is filtered by uid works with an orderby. Why isn't the second query working?

Query filtered by user id

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('alerts')
      .where('access', arrayContains: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid)
      .orderBy('createdAt', descending: true)
      .snapshots(),
```

Query filtered by patient ID

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('alerts')
      .where('patientId', isEqualTo: patient.id)
      //.orderBy('createdAt', descending: false)
      .snapshots(),
```

I've commented out the orderBy in this query because it causes it to not return any results. Without using the orderBy I get the results I want just not in the order I want them.

The Alerts have a field called 'access' that contains user ids if that alert should be associated with that user. The 'patient id' on Alerts relates the alert to a specific patient.
The first query returns all alerts that should be viewed by the user.
The second query returns just the alerts for a specific patient.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66771552/13701546 Check this

Comment: @SimonSot that might help but I already have an index set up on this table for createdAt should I add another one where I also include the patientID field?

Comment: Yes you should add for where too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create indexes for both queries in your Firebase.

Answer (score -1):

Coming back to this because I actually ended up fixing it. Like the other user mentioned I needed to create indexes in firebase in order for this to work. So I went to firebase created an index for my alerts collection and added patientID and creationDate both as descending to an index. Saved that index, waited for it to post to firebase, went back to flutter and it worked.

After that I ran into another issue where the alerts were not displaying in the right order so I simply changed the descending in the orderBy to true instead of false and it all worked out.